# CSS3 / IE Compatability and Shadows and Borders

Tags: php, internet-explorer, css

I have a box, more specifically a div that will serve as a log in box on a front page of a website. I apply the CSS3 effects moz, webkit, and box-shadow. The method works perfectly in all browsers EXCEPT for IE. I have IE 7. What can I do to make this compatible with all internet explorer browsers 6 and up?

```
#login_portal {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 125px;
    margin-left: 125px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;

    border: 1px solid #CCC;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE9 should work just fine. For IE6-7-8 you can use http://css3pie.com/ but then you need to think if it really makes sense to make worse the already poor performance in IE for a simple box-shadow...

Answer (score 2):

Give [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) a try. It makes Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features

Answer (score 1):

[*Can I Use?* says `box-shadow` isn't supported until IE9.](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow) Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter property to make CSS3 compatible with IE7+.
See the example below :

```
.box-shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #969696; /* for Firefox 3.5+ */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #969696; /* for Safari and Chrome */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#969696', Direction=145, Strength=3);
}
```

This this [link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/) for more details.

Comment: I have tried those examples and it seems to not work at all in IE. Can I get help with the code please?

Comment: It is working in my app with IE8. Anyways CSS3 PIE may be the solution for you then. See this : [link](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/)

Comment: The problem I ran into was it shadowed ALL elements within the div. I just wanted to shadow the div.